# How to write this natural language sentence as a predicate logic formula?

Tags: predicate-logic

I should write the following sentence as a predicate logic formula:

"It is not true that all soccer players are fearless and it is not true that some sailors aren't fearless."

I would write it like this, but I'm not sure if it is correct: $\neg(\forall x)F(x)\land\neg (\exists y)\neg F(y)$ .

Especially  I'm not sure about those variables and quantifiers since once we are talking about ALL soccer players and second we are talking about SOME sailors - in other words, two different object are quantified.

Comment: NO; you have to use suitable predicates for Soccer players and Sailors.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? How should than the formula look like?

Comment: Your formula reads: "Not everything is fearless and everything is fearless"

Comment: Start with the simple parts: "all soccer players are fearless" that is $\forall x (\text {SocPlay}(x) \to \text {Fearless}(x))$.

Comment: Oh I see. So for example like this? $\neg(\forall x) (SocPlay(x)\implies Fear(x))\land\neg (\exists x) (Sailor(x)\implies\neg Fear(x))$

Comment: "some sailors aren't fearless" is $\exists x (\text {Sailor} \land \lnot \text {Fearless}(x))$. See [Categorical propositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism#Types).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I now has to find out, if the following sentence is a logical consequence of the previous formula: "Therefore some brave people are sailors." I know that in order to find out a logical consequence I has to find out wheter the conjunction of the previous formula with the negation of this sentence is a contradiction.  But how should I formalize this consequence sentence? Is the following formalization of that sentence correct?: $\exists x (people(x)\land sailors(x))$

Comment: I'm not an English native speaker, but I think that "brave" and "fearless" mean the same.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to write "fearless" instead of "brave".

Comment: Is the formalization I proposed for the consequence sentence correct than? I am not sure since People is a superset for Sailors and Soccers.

Comment: No, it is not; it must be $\exists x (\text {Fearless}(x) \land \text {Sailor}(x))$. From a formal point of view, Brave and Fearless are not the same.